# AJAX php code inserting NULL and not input values to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, mysqli

I am trying to insert 2 values interchangeably to my database - my Select element with `name=toctquantsel` and my Input element with `name=toctquant`. When my Select element is hidden, the value of my Input will be inserted to the database, and vise versa. I was able to achieve with my php code alone, however when doing this with AJAX, I get the error message, "`Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'toctquant' cannot be null`". Again, I did not get this error when not using AJAX. How do I fix this so I can insert my values to the database without having to change my database columns to NULL?

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: "This is the AJAX code which inserts the values to the database"  No.  AJAX does not insert into a database.  Maybe it makes a request to PHP code, which in turn executes a MySQL query via the mysqli library, but none of what you're showing would actually be inserting into the database.

Comment: Does your jQuery code live in a `.js` file or is it in the same page as your HTML/PHP code?

Comment: You're using `event.preventDefault();` but you never declared the variable `event`. It should be `$(document).on("submit", "#toctform", function(event){`.

Comment: @PatrickQ Ok, ok excuse my wrong use of terminology then. So it "makes a request to my php code" then. I'm not sure how that answers my question though?

Comment: Your AJAX call never sets the value of `toctquant` in the `data:` option.

Comment: Why do you have two inputs with `name="toctquant"`?

Comment: @misner3456 It doesn't answer your question, but if your question is regarding why data isn't properly inserted into your database, it would be helpful if you showed the code that actually _does_ the inserting.

Comment: @PatrickQ My jQuery code is within script tags and posted right below the html form element that I posted. Sorry it took me 45 mins to reply, I was at my job when I posted this.

Comment: @Barmar To answer your first question: the `data:` option does set the value of `toctquant` - `toctquant`'s id is `#inphid` and `#inphid` is situated in the variable `inputValue` which is shown as the second parameter in the `data:` option.

Comment: The parameters that are sent in AJAX come from the keys of the `data:` object, not the names from the form.

Comment: @PatrickQ So thanks to Barmar, I found my mistake was in the AJAX code. I wasn't inserting the actual names of the elements into the data option. But that's now been fixed

Comment: FYI, if you had shown your PHP code from the beginning, this likely would have been resolved in a matter of minutes, as the issue would have been obvious.

Comment: @Barmar Definitely makes sense, now I know, thanks!

Comment: @PatrickQ I assumed it had nothing to do with the PHP code since everything worked fine until I started adding the AJAX. But thanks for correcting me earlier, I still have a lot to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit the form normally, the form fields will be put in `$_POST['toctquantsel`]`and`$_POST['toctquant']`. In your AJAX call, you have

```
data: {selectValueBox: selectValue, inputValueBox: inputValue},
```

When you use AJAX, the parameter names sent to PHP come from the `data:` object, not the names of the form fields. So these fields will be in `$_POST['selectValueBox']` and `$_POST['inputValueBox']`. To make your AJAX code work with the same PHP code on the server, you need to change that to:

```
data: {toctquantsel: selectValue, toctquant: inputValue},
```

Comment: Ahh so _that's_ what it was! This is my first time using AJAX. I didn't know the first parameters should use the exact same name as the elements. Thanks for pointing that out to me - completely resolved the issue - Thanks, many thanks!

Comment: I know it's a stupid question, but how did you think the parameter names would be set when you used AJAX?

Comment: I'm new to AJAX and couldn't find an AJAX guide that fit with my issue, so I mixed a bunch of AJAX code and just based my values on those.